# nginx proxy_pass of PUT with no Content-Length header returns 411

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-411

I am having trouble with nginx proxy_pass and PUT without a Content-Length header returning a 411 error.

What I run to test this:

```
# curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/
<html>
<head><title>411 Length Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
# touch temp
# curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/ -T temp
{"response": "ok"}
```

Relevant configuration:

```
# Proxy to Backend Server
server {
    listen localhost:8080;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend_server;
    }
}
```

I found this post which seems to be the same problem:

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,72279,72279#msg-72279

Is there a way to get nginx to proxy PUT requests WITHOUT a Content-Length header?

Does a newer version of nginx NOT suffer from this bug/limitation?

Comment: Duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/164220/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-nginx-411-content-length-required-errors

Comment: Note that PUT with no body works from curl. Not sure if that is curl adding the zero header or nginx assuming that no header means 0 length.

Comment: "Nginx assuming that no header means zero length"  That is what the HTTP spec says http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html   "The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the request's message-headers." No length = No body.

Comment: They have fixed this in more recent versions of nginx apparently but I haven't had time to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to `nginx >= 1.4.1` (`1.3.9` or `1.4.0` would be enough, but have security issues thx @elhefe - see comments) or install [NginxHttpChunkinModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpChunkinModule) as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/164220/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-nginx-411-content-length-required-errors). There are [official packages](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) for Debian and RedHat families.

**Debian**:

- wheezy backports (currently 1.4.4-1)

  add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
  ```

  run and install nginx version of your choice (`nginx-full`, `nginx-light`, `nginx-naxsi`)

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get -t wheezy-backports install nginx-full
  ```
- nginx.org package (stable version is currently 1.4.4):

  ```
  wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
  apt-key add nginx_signing.key
  ```

  add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
  deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
  ```

  remove current nginx packages:

  ```
  apt-get remove nginx-full nginx-common
  ```

  update packages list:

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install nginx
  ```

  For Debian-like behaviour change update `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

  ```
  user  www-data;
  ```

  and add at the end of `http` section

  ```
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  ```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't upgrade to nginx 1.3.9 or 1.4.0: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-announce/2013/000112.html